# kendo checkbox checked binding. Not able to bind to an array of checkboxes

Tags: binding, checkbox, kendo-ui

I have an array of checkboxes and I would like to use it as an array, for example set single iitems in a group of options and retrieve the values of the group.
For a single checkbox I'm able to set it and get the click event, as an array I don't get anything.

**HTML code :**

```
    <div class="k-group" id="chkbox-options">
    <label>
        Red
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="Red" data-bind="checked: colors" />
        Green
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" value="Green" data-bind="checked: colors" />
        Blue
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk3" value="Blue"  data-bind="checked: colors" />
    </label>
    </div>
```

**Javascript code :**

```
    <script  type="text/javascript">
        var colordata = null;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            colordata = kendo.observable({
                colors: ["Blue"]
            });
            kendo.bind($("chkbox-options"), colordata);
            $("#dump-values").click(function () {
                kendoConsole.log(colordata.colors.toString());
            });
            $("#chk1").click(function () {
                kendoConsole.log("click chk1");
                if (this.checked) {
                    kendoConsole.log("click chk1 true");
                }
            });
         });
    </script>
```

I can get the click event on a single checkbox, while I cannot set the values of the checkboxes in `kendo.observable` in the field var colordata.

I saw a similar example in the kendo documentation but I'm not able to make it work.

Thanks for your help

Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couple of points:
1. in kendo.bind # is missing for the div id chkbox-options
2. you need to read the changed colors inside the change event of the the observable object. The change happens after the click event so inside click event you always see the old data.

I have corrected your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/whizkid747/rPjjJ/4/

```
var colordata = null;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            colordata = kendo.observable({
                colors: ["Blue"]
            });
            kendo.bind($("#chkbox-options"), colordata);

            colordata.bind("change", function(e) {
                var selectedColors = '';

                $.each(colordata.colors, function(key, value){
                    selectedColors = selectedColors + " " + value;
                });
                if(colordata.colors.length == 0){
                    console.log('no colors selected');
                }else{
                console.log('selected colors:' + selectedColors);  
                }
            });            
         });
```

Comment: if this answer is what you are looking for, please mark it as answer so that its helpful to others seeking answer to similar questions.

Comment: it answers the question thanks. Sorry for the blindness, I thought there was a button to tag the question as answered, but I don't see it.